# copy paste in excel suddenly pastes weird symbols and separators

Tags: excel

As I copy cells in excel and paste them into text editor I get unwanted symbols and separators. this is a very new issue I'm unsure what i've done to cause it, anyone familiar with how to fix?

For instance. My B1 cell has $20,000 in it, when i select the cell and paste it into a text app such as Drafts, the output i get is:

```
| ----- |
|  $20,000 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Excel cell borders are being pasted. This is probably a feature of the text editor (in this case, Drafts). It might be possible to turn off this option in Drafts so that only the raw text is pasted.

If not, the easiest workaround is probably to have a plain text editor such as Notepad++ open; paste your copied cell into that (to lose the formatting), then re-copy and paste into Drafts.

Alternatively, remove the borders from your Excel cell(s).

Given you say this has suddenly started happening, you might accidentally have changed the default 'paste' option in Drafts (or maybe you haven't tried copying Excel cells with borders before?).